# Codeigniter form not redirecting to expected URL

Tags: html, codeigniter-2, forms

This is my URL of the form:

http://localhost/MCQQuizWebApp/index.php

This is the form:

```
<?php echo form_open('front_controller/show_result'); ?>
        <?php
            $ques_no = 1;
            foreach($questions as $question)
            {
                echo '<div class="section">';
                echo '<div class="question">';
                echo 'Q' . $ques_no . '. ' .$question->ques_desc;
                echo '</div>';
                foreach($choices[$question->ques_id] as $choice)
                {
                    echo '<div class="choice">';
                    echo $choice;
                    echo '</div>';
                }
                $ques_no++;
                echo '</div><br>';
            }
        ?>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    <?php echo  form_close();?>
```

This is my controller :

```
class Front_controller extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
                $this->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function show_result(){

    }
```

form_open('front_controller/show_result'); does not redirect to the URL http://localhost/MCQQuizWebApp/index.php/front_controller/show_result

generated code from

```
form_open('front_controller/show_result');
```

is

```
<form action="http://::1/MCQQuizWebApp/index.php/front_controller" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, just echo this on your front `<form role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo site_url('front_controller/show_result');?>">`